# Browse VC6 DLL variables content (DEBUG)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dll, visual-c++-6

I'm trying to debug an old VC6 dll, I manage to go through the code but unfortunately my vc9 debugger doesn't show the content of the variables in the dll. (browsing info I guess)

I manage to see the content of my dll when I debug it in VC6 but I would prefer to be able to debug in the same time as my managed code.

Maybe I'm missing some compilation parameters in my VC6 project. Would be great if someone had any idea, I'll then gain a lot of time.

Thanks in advance, 
Boris

Answer (score 1):

Starting (I think) with VC8 (VS2005) the debugger no longer supports Codeview symbols, so you'll need to make sure that when you build the DLL in VC6 you specify that it create a PDB symbol file.

from the command line it's /PDB:

In the IDE go to the project's Link tab and Debug category - Make sure "Debug info" and "Microsoft format" are selected.

VS2008's debugger should be able to load and use the VC6 PDB symbols.

Interestingly, when debugging a VC6 binary the VS2008 debugger won't show any variables in the 'Locals' windows, but it shows their values just fine in the 'Autos' and 'Watch' windows and will also show their values in tooltip pop-ups.  Weird.

Comment: It actually works but only for few variables, but not all of them. The pdb file was not generated in the right place. I don't manage to have all variables in debug,  think it's an issue with different kind of string (VC6 agains VC9 are not using the same basic_string). But if someone know how to debug that!