# Most variables not displayed when debugging VC6 code in VS 2005 and 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-6

Visual Studio 2010 is unable to display anything but the values of local concrete variables (i.e. int, bool, etc.) when debugging code that was built using Visual Studio 6.

The Visual Studio 6 build is generating a pdb file, "Debug info" and "Microsoft format" are selected as suggested in response to the following question: [Browse VC6 DLL variables content (DEBUG)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225163/browse-vc6-dll-variables-content-debug)

For example in the following code, the only variable which I can see the value for is 'var'. By 'see' I mean that the variable appears in the "Locals" or "Auto" window with a value, I get a value in a tool tip, or that the variable name is resolved when I enter it in the Watch window.

It seems I cannot see 'num' as it is an argument to the function, I can't see 'm_member' as it is a class member. I can't see 'stackMem' or 'heapMem' as they are not simple types.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
MyClass() : m_member(0) {}
int aMethod(int num)
{
    m_member = m_member + num;
    return m_member;
}
private:
int m_member;
};

void main()
{
MyClass* heapMem = new MyClass();
MyClass stackMem;

int var = heapMem->aMethod(5);
var = stackMem.aMethod(10);
}
```

Is there anything I can do to better be able to debug old VC6 code in a newer debug environment like VS 2010?

Comment: Thanks Bo. Yes, my question is very similar. Unfortunately I have generated a pdb file and made sure "Debug info" and "Microsoft format" are selected in the VC6 build as suggested and I still can only see (it looks like) local variables that are concrete types (int, bool etc.) regardless of the window I look in (Locals, Auto, Watch, tool tip)

Comment: @Reuben It may be useful to edit the question and add the information you gave in the comment above, and also include a link to the possible duplicate and brief explanation saying that you are aware of that question and how yours is different.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember how VC6 used to work; but in VS2005 and more recent Visual Studio editions, there are be different views (tabs/windows) available when debugging that you can dock.

Watch, Auto (auto variables), Locals, Callstack...

They are (should be) available from the Debug menu when you start debugging.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Max. Unfortunately my question is not about the location of the various debug windows in the IDE, but the fact that I don't see any of the variables (apart from a few locals) for the current call stack in the "Auto" window (for example).